# Search for text in BAT Files

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have 1000+ batch files in a folder, and I have to find all files that contains `"Connect to"`.

I tried via PowerShell:

```
Select-String -Path C:\BAT -Pattern "Connect to"
```

But I get "Access Denied". Probably because it’s a Folder and select-string doesn't work with folders?

Comment: It is a permission issue.  Nothing to do with the select-string cmdlet.  You can run the PS As Admin by right click the PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Correct, it cannot "read" a folder. `Get-ChildItem C:\BAT -File -Filter *.bat |Select-String -Pattern 'Connect to' -CaseSensitive`

Comment: A batch file could use findstr.exe: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RMC:"Connect to" "C:\BAT\*.bat"```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` parameters only accept *file* paths** to specify what files to search through.

The error you're seeing stems from **mistakenly passing a *directory* path** (it is the same error you get in Windows PowerShell when you try to read a directory with `Get-Content`, for instance, such as `Get-Content C:\Windows`).<sup>[1]</sup>

To search only `*.bat` files inside `C:\BAT`, append the [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) pattern to your path:

```bash
Select-String -Path C:\BAT\*.bat -Pattern "Connect to"
```

To search both `*.bat` and `*.cmd` files, use `*` as part of the `-Path` argument and add `-Include *.bat, *.cmd` to filter by *multiple* patterns:

```bash
Select-String -Path C:\BAT\* -Include *.bat, *.cmd -Pattern "Connect to"
```

To search *all* files inside `C:\BAT`, just `*` as the pattern will do:

```bash
Select-String -Path C:\BAT\* -Pattern "Connect to"
```

**Caveat:**

- In *Windows PowerShell*, if `C:\BAT` has *subdirectories* that are matched by the wildcard, each will result in a non-terminating `Access denied` error. Use `-ErrorAction Silence` / `-ErrorAction Ignore` to silence / ignore them.
- The problem has been fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), where directories among the wildcard matches are quietly *skipped*.

  - Note that this also applies to mistakenly providing a directory as *input* via `-Path` / `-LiteralPath`; that is, in PowerShell 7+ your original attempt would be a *quiet no-op*.

---

If you need **more control over what files to search**, **pipe the output from a [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call to `Select-String`**, which notably gives you the ability to search *recursively* in a directory subtree, via `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`; e.g.:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath C:\BAT -Recurse -Include *.bat, *.cmd | 
  Select-String -Pattern 'Connect to'
```

The technique can also be used to avoid potential error messages from *subdirectories* when searching *all* files in Windows PowerShell; the `-File` switch limits output to just files:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath C:\BAT -File | Select-String -Pattern 'Connect to'
```

---

<sup>[1] Note in PowerShell (Core) 7+ `Get-Content` now emits a more descriptive error message.</sup>